# Can this MySQL query be more efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql

**UPDATE**  Here's a sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0822/1/0

I have a MySQL database of apps (itunes_id), each app id has a comments field.  To preserve a history, every time a comment is changed, a new row of data is added.  In the query below, I just want a list of the latest entry (highest id) of every app (itunes_id).

Here are the headers of my db:

```
id  (key and auto increment)
itunes_id
comments 
date
```

This query is getting the latest entry for a given itunes_id.  How can I make this query more efficient?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM Apps
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ) AS apps1
    GROUP BY itunes_id
) AS apps2
LIMIT 0 , 25
```

Comment: can you create a sql fiddle for us?

Comment: Stop selecting `*`. That's like going to the grocery store and filling your shopping cart with every product in food group you want.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk awful advice, sometimes `*` is necessary

Comment: Actually WootWoot, the advise based on your example might be good advise to not use so many `Select *` you don't need that many Selects personally

Comment: @Woot4Moo Give me a sec, I'll build a sql fiddle.  Thanks.

Comment: @Woot4Moo The question is about efficiency. Selecing all is [not efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc).

Comment: @DJKRAZE  That's what I was thinking.  Way too many SELECTS but how do I reduce them.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk myopic view in my experienced opinion.

Comment: In my experience, `select *` isn't lazy, it is sloppy. @Woot4Moo, would you please post an example where `select *` is necessary? I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Not sure how to respond to that... ***Any*** experienced DBA will tell you it's not efficient.

Comment: @BryanH sure.  I create a materialized view that requires all of the columns in my table, but also does a very lengthy computation. I then proceed to create a regular view on top of this materialized view to facilitate user queries so they don't know the structure of my table.  Let me see if I can make a fiddle to illustrate what I mean (assume a placeholder function that takes an hour to execute).

Comment: @Woot4Moo Once you do that, I will create an equal view that uses a column list. Then, we can both add 50 columns to the parent tables and compare how efficient they are.

Comment: @Woot4Moo . . . The order by in the innermost query is not correct coding practice.  The results are indeterminate.  You can read the MySQL documentation for more information about this . . .http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk and yet my explain plan is THE EXACT SAME in every query I have ever written in Oracle

Comment: @Woot4Moo You're moving more data... so how is moving more (unnecessary) data more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query uses a subquery which separately gets the maximum `ID` for every `itunes_ID`. The result of the subquery is then join back on the original table provided that it matches on two columns: `itunes_ID` and `ID`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Apps a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  itunes_id, MAX(ID) max_id
            FROM    Apps
            GROUP   BY itunes_id
        ) b ON a.itunes_id = b.itunes_id AND
                a.ID = b.max_ID
LIMIT   0, 25
```

For faster performance, create a compound column `INDEX` on columns `itunes_ID` and `ID`. EG,

```
ALTER TABLE Apps ADD INDEX (itunes_ID, ID)
```

Comment: Nice.  I want to make this more efficient because I'm getting a lot of traffic.  I'm willing to make changes to the db as needed to make this as efficient as possible (even willing to change db types).  I added the index column, how do I use it?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ff75/1/0

Comment: You have nothing to do with it..it's the server that will use it :D see the executiom plan, youll see tht it uses the index

Comment: If you are able to make changes to the DB, I would recommend changing your DB structure to keep the history in a separate table. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 1):

For a similar approach, I use a "recent" boolean field to mark records containing the latest version. This requires an UPDATE query on every insert (deactivate the previous recent record), but allows for a quick select query. Alternatively, you could maintain two tables, one with the recent records, the other one with the history for each app.

**EDIT**: Maybe you can try a table similar to this:

- id int not null auto_increment primary key
- version int not null
- main_id int null
- recent boolean not null
- app varchar(32) not null
- comment varchar(200) null

You can use the column "main_id" to point to the record with version 1.

Answer (score 0):

*I just want the latest entry (highest id) for a given app (itunes_id)*

This will do it

```
SELECT MAX(id), comments FROM Apps WHERE itunes_id = "iid";
```

or

```
SELECT id, comments FROM Apps WHERE itunes_id = "iid" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Where `iid` is the itunes id for which you want the latest comment.

Make sure `id` and `itunes_id` are indexed in a [composite index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) for maximum efficiency.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write "I just want a list of the latest entry (highest id) of every app (itunes_id)."  I updated the text int he question above.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM Apps
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ) AS apps1
    GROUP BY itunes_id
) AS apps2
LIMIT 0 , 25
```

will not select the oldest record (you cannot assume the generated key will always be the "oldest").  What you want is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM Apps
        where some_date = (select max(some_date) from Apps limit 1)
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ) AS apps1
    GROUP BY itunes_id
) AS apps2
LIMIT 0 , 25
```

Comment: Good point. But you also added another select statement.  Doesn't that also make the query even slower?