# Difference of two kind of Selecting all columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, select

What is the difference in this two SQL queries besides the lenght of the code?

```
SELECT * from tblPerson

SELECT id, name age from tblPerson
```

NOTE: I am selecting all columns in here, in the second code, that is all the columns of the table, I am not selecting specific locations.

Comment: `SELECT *` is a quick - but **dirty** way of selecting. You could run into unexpected and unpleasant surprises e.g. if someone else on your team adds three `XML` and `VARBINARY(MAX)` columns to your table without you knowing (and you suddenly select **much more** data than anticipated). **Don't do it** in production code - just don't.

Comment: Also see: [Which is faster/best? SELECT * or SELECT column1, colum2, column3, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512)

Answer (score 2):

One obvious difference is indeed the length of the code. Another difference is the maintaineability (don't know how to write that word) i.e. adding a column later to 'tblPerson' will change the result.

Comment: yes I already said that to my question, in terms of maintainability yes ur right

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.

`SELECT *` means that you are selecting all columns to show on the result list. 
`SELECT col1, ...` specifies only the column you want to be shown.

Comment: Even though they are *functionally* the same, I think there are some subtle differences in query plans.  The conventional wisdom is to use column lists wherever possible.

Comment: ahh, even if I select a table with 20 columns without using the astersisk, it will have no difference? Some of my friends say that using asterisk is more faster than selecting all without asterisk.

Comment: @RoronoaZoro don't trust your friends. trust the optimizer `:D`