# mysql * selection with prepended custom columns

Tags: mysql, select

Is there a way to add specific custom columns/messages before the columns selected using * columns?
This works fine.

> select *** , 'User_Msg_1'** from rrc;

whereas i need something like this

> select **'User_Msg_1', *** from rrc;

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `*`, and certainly shouldn't be relying on the order of columns in the resultset.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using "shouldn't" without providing [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/65512/1346207).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rrc.*`:

```
SELECT 'User_Msg_1', rrc.* FROM rrc;
```

or make a cartesian product on the relation {("User_Msg_1")}:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'User_Msg_1' FROM DUAL), rrc
```