# Copy row from one table to another with a additional primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO event_log_tracker_table 
SELECT * FROM event_tracker_table WHERE eventid = '560'
```

However I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

The columns match exactly the same except for one thing...

I added one more column (`eventlogid`) in `event_log_tracker_table` to be a primary key. How can I insert a row, from another table and have it add to a primary key in the new table?

Below is a structure of the tables.

```
event_log_tracker_table (24 columns)
-----------------------
eventlogid - PK
eventid - INT
//
//  22 other columns
//

event_tracker_table (23 columns)
-----------------------
eventid - PK
//
//  22 other columns
//
```

I have tried to do this:

```
INSERT INTO event_log_tracker_table 
SELECT null, * FROM event_tracker_table WHERE eventid = '560'
```

Comment: `SELECT NULL, event_tracker_table.* FROM ...`?

Comment: @eggyal that worked, can you write that in an answer an i'll accept it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql \* selection with prepended custom columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002294/mysql-selection-with-prepended-custom-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [`SELECT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html):

> - Use of an unqualified **`*`** with other items in the select list may produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified **`tbl_name.*`** reference
>
>   ```
>   SELECT AVG(score), t1.* FROM t1 ...
>   ```

Therefore, instead of `SELECT NULL, *` you could should qualify the wildcard:

```
INSERT INTO event_log_tracker_table 
SELECT NULL, event_tracker_table.*
FROM   event_tracker_table
WHERE  eventid = '560'
```