# How to convert empty string to null in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to replace/convert empty string with `NULL` in `SELECT` query without altering the table or updating the table.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`NULLIF`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#NULLIF) function is supported on most major RDBMS's.

```
SELECT NULLIF(MyColumn, '') FROM MyTable
```

This will return `NULL` for any row if `MyColumn` is equal to the empty string.

Comment: never used it but glad to know it.

Comment: This does not seem to actually replace the empty string value with null within the original table.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Correct. `SELECT` statements will not modify the original table. You'd need to use an `UPDATE` for that;  either use `UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = NULLIF(MyColumn, '')` or `UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = NULL WHERE MyColumn = ''`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE RTRIM(Column) WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE Column END AS [Column]
```

Comment: what about using something with `*`

Comment: I mean something like `SELECT magic(*) FROM table` or `SELECT mytable.* FROM mytable` because none of these things are working with that.

Comment: you have to specify which column you are testing to determine if it's empty.  You can't apply logic to a wildcard.

Comment: hmmm thats interesting.

Comment: @mega6382 No, you'd have to handle each column individually. You probably shouldn't be using `SELECT *` anyway, see [Which is faster/best? SELECT * or SELECT column1, colum2, column3, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc)

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thanks for telling. Because it is always best practice to use faster methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE Length(Col) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE Col END
```