# select all fields with common start phrase in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 77 fields in MySQL. Quite a number of them start with the same prefix "mt3_".
Instead of writing them all out, I wanted to use this syntax to select only those fields from the table that start with "mt3_":

```
SELECT tablename.mt3_* from tablename;
```

However this does not work... What is the correct syntax to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: There is none. Either select all columns or name the ones you want to select

Comment: @juergend There is a way, just writing an answer now.

Comment: @worldofjr Dynamic SQL?

Comment: @ForguesR select the column names as a subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly, but you can ask MySQL for the column names in that table and filter with wild card character `%` in a `WHERE` statement, like this;

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
AND column_name LIKE 'mt3_%'
```

You can then run another query with a loop of these results (I'm guessing you're using PHP and mysqli);

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $cols[] = $row['column_name'];
}

$colnames = explode(",",$cols);

$sql = "SELECT $colnames FROM tablename"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not using PHP but Python, although in this work I'm doing everything just with mysql directly. I understand the first part. Can I use the second part too in mysql, or how would I go about that -with PHP I guess...?

Comment: Ah Python ... `"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE " + ' '.join(['%s = 1' % name for name in columns])`

Comment: I don't think it's possible without using some sort of procedural language (or just typing the column names in).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that without dynamic SQL and honestly I can not recommend doing something like this.

If you care enough to `SELECT` only certain fields then you also probably care enough about best practices and it is a [best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65532/1980659) to specify all the fields *you want* inside a `SELECT` query.

Use `SELECT *` for a single fast retrieval.  If you are actually coding something then take the time to specify the fields you want.