# Data Set in BI Publisher

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

While creating a dataset in BI Publisher, which one is more optimized?

```
Select * from <table_name>  
OR
select column1, column2 from table_name?
```

Is there any difference between mentioning specific columns and doing a select all statement? provided that all the columns are being used in the report.

Comment: If the resulting column are the same, then they are equally 'optimised'. But Select * has the unfortunate side effect that if you add a new column to the table it comes through automatically and that can create unexpected consequences. Beside select * is generally considered 'lazy' as in you haven't considered what columns you actually need.

Answer (score 1):

```
select column1, column2 from table_name
```

Above should be used, as the column names would be mapped to the names used in your `.rtf` file.

We use a `.xdo` or `.xdm` file for mapping of DB columns to the variables used in `.rtf` file.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with user FallAndLearn.
But regardless of whether .rtf file is being used, naming the columns explicitly is [always recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc) from an optimization and SQL tuning perspective.