# DataFlow - Read from BigQuery partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Using DataFlow SDK 2.x, I would like to read data from BigQuery partitioned table.

The only option I found so far is using `BigQueryIO.Read.fromQuery(String query)` method and query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = 'yyyy-MM-dd'`.

Is there any other way to read from partitioned BigQuery table in DataFlow?

Comment: This is the correct way. If you use a normal read, it will read the entire table into your pipeline, regardless if it's a partitioned table or not.

Comment: @GrahamPolley, thanks for the answer. Do you plan adding method-level support for querying partitioned tables?

Comment: You can also use a partition decorator, read from "table$yyyyMMdd" should work I believe. There are currently no plans on adding more explicit support as far as I'm aware; if you need it, feel free to file a JIRA at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM or post on the user@ mailing list.

Comment: @jkff Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: It is documented at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

Answer (score 0):

Well to be honest, there is a better way to do it. Two ways to do it for performance and one if you look into BigQuery API.

So recall that

```
    Select * from `tableName`
```

is an expensive operation for your database. In order to speed up the read time you could instead:

```
    Select <field1>, <field2>, ...., from `tableName`
```

Of course, listing all the field names is not possible in many cases, but you will get roughly twice the speed up.

But instead of doing that you can follow the example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/41641930674e95b02d0143f07bd8f80086762840/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/bigquery/snippets/BigQuerySnippets.java#L440). This will also give you roughly twice the speed up as well and is much more convenient.

Let me know if you need a coded example of the link provided, Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please elaborate more why using BigQuery API is faster than using BigQueryIO.Read?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I misread the question and mistook BigQueryIO for BigQuery.
That being said, your BigQueryIO uses the BigQuery API underneath as from what I can see from [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java). So BigQueryIO would be the same speed as BigQuery or faster depending on the number of workers that are assigned to reading the table. Thus, it is faster with BigQueryIO, but the data read is passed as a PCollection. However, my suggestion of naming columns is better

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc