# What is the difference between SELECT * and SELECT value

Tags: php, mysql, session, select

What's the difference between

```
    $query = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE username='$username' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $email = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
```

and

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $email = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
```

They both return the same value, is there any more effective way to do that?

Comment: I think all the answers covered it pretty thoroughly, but for a concrete example; imagine the performance difference if `users` had a large blob field that stored a high-resolution profile pic.

Comment: Basically, never use evil `SELECT *`, and you will do just fine.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful

Answer (score 1):

`select *` will return values for all the columns in the table that have rows that match your predicate, while `select column_name` will only return the values in the `column_name` column for the rows that match your predicate.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT column` returns only the value of that column. `SELECT *` returns the value of every column in the table. If you were to `print_r($row)` in your second code block you would see a lot more elements in the array than just `$row['email']`.

There is a good Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc) which talks about the relative performance differences of `SELECT *` and `SELECT column`. @Uueerdo's point about one of the other fields having a huge blob causing performance issues is also very valid.

You can also run into issues with `SELECT *` when you are `JOIN`ing tables, if both tables have identically named columns then the values from one table can overwrite the other when data is returned to your application framework.

Answer (score 0):

`*` is least efficient if you only want `email` because you are returning every columns value.

You also should parameterize your query.

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE username= ? ";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

- Selects All which means it will return all columns But "select email" will return the column "email" which is more effecient. You can also  select many columns like:
  "select id,email from users" .