# Most efficient way of getting mariaDB/SQL record count

Tags: sql, mariadb

A question on a simple SQL statement, but one which I sometimes wonder over. Thought I'd see if anyone knew the answer to.

When counting the records in a table using a simple SQL statement, which has the least overheard:

```
1) SELECT COUNT(single_primary_field) FROM table, i.e. SELECT COUNT(user_ID) FROM users;

2) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
```

I initially thought the first may be quickest. But perhaps not having a specific field to associate with makes the second quicker?

Probably makes very little difference speed wise either way.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is faster/best? SELECT \* or SELECT column1, colum2, column3, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc)

Answer (score 3):

`COUNT(column)` counts only selected column and ignore the null values.

`COUNT(*)` count rows and don't care values in the columns.

Using `COUNT(*)` is a better way for counting rows.

Answer (score 0):

Count(*) is most efficent way to count according to mysql:
[Count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)

Answer (score 0):

Have a read through https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/explain/ to look at what type of indexing your query is using, it usually hints at its performance.

I think Count(*) is going to be the fastest because maria does store a running count.