# SELECT statement in SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I am new in SQL DEVELOPER tools and I have written a simple select statement like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM employee;
```

it worked fine but there was a yellow warning mark underneath SELECT and I clicked on that and my query changes into the following query:

```sql
SELECT "A1"."EMPLOYEE_ID" "EMPLOYEE_ID","A1"."FIRST_NAME" "FIRST_NAME","A1"."LAST_NAME" "LAST_NAME","A1"."SALARY" "SALARY", "A1"."DEPARTMENT_ID" "DEPARTMENT_ID","A1"."MANAGER_ID" "MANAGER_ID","A1"."HIRE_DATE" "HIRE_DATE"
FROM "INTRO_USER"."EMPLOYEE" "A1";
```

My Quest is what is the difference between these two queries? although their output is the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is faster/best? SELECT \* or SELECT column1, colum2, column3, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc)

Answer (score 0):

The glob `*` has been expanded to all column of the table. The table name  `EMPLOYEE` is aliased to `A1` to make it shorter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have checked it and changed aliased A1 to B1(query works perfectly fine if I change A1 to B!) and still, I got the yellow mark under SELECT and it showed A1. why so? can't we aliased our table name as the way we want?

Comment: I don't know more. This is my limit :')

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are seeing is called 'SQL Text Expansion,' and it's setup to allow you to see what your query would look like if you were working with one or more VIEWS.

For example, `SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES` is quite complicated. This feature allows you to see what's actually involved when running that SQL.

[image]

https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/12/sql-developer-and-a-12c-magic-trick/

There is probably no change or expected delta in the performance or execution plan of the 2 versions of your query.

Comment: Great - I wasn't aware of this. (You can tell that I use the keyboard to type my queries - very rarely touch the mouse!) I added a link for those - like me - who are seeing this here for the first time. If you have a better link, by all means please change it.