# How to Optimize the Query in SQL Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle

This query is taking 5 hrs to extract 1M rows out of 120M data.

```
select * from cc.ALC_TR_LS
where INV_TRN_ID > 0 
order by INV_TRN_ID asc ;
fetch first 1000000 rows only;
```

Note : INV_TRN_ID is a identity column.
Need to optimize this query. Please suggest.

Comment: is there any index on INV_TRN_ID ?

Comment: [Which is faster/best? SELECT * or SELECT column1, colum2, column3, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65512)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing if you observe *performance issues* is to check the [execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122).

I'll simulate your case with this sample data

```
create table large_tab as
select rownum id, 
rpad('x',2000,'y') pad
from dual connect by level <= 20000;
```

The execution plan for the query (your simplified)

```
select * from large_tab
where id > 0
order by id
fetch first 10000 rows only;
```

is as follows

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name      | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |           | 10000 |     9M|       | 10223   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                    |           | 10000 |     9M|       | 10223   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK|           | 20000 |    38M|    39M| 10223   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | LARGE_TAB | 20000 |    38M|       |  1842   (1)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=10000)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "LARGE_TAB"."ID")<=10000)
   3 - filter("ID">0)
```

The critical point is in line 2 where you need to sort 1M rows (10K in my case).

Note that you sort *rows* not `ID`s, so you need a lot of *temp space* as shown in the execution plan column `TempSpc`.

This is where you spend the elapsed time.

**Alternative**

If the table is rather *static* you may use *two step* approach.

First get the highest `ID` of your first 1M rows, than get all data up to this `ID`

*Get the Upper Bound ID*

```
select id from large_tab
where id > 0
order by id
offset 9999 rows fetch first 1  rows only;
```

The plan is similar, but as you order only ID's that are compact, the *temp space is gone*

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |           | 20000 |   761K|  1844   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                    |           | 20000 |   761K|  1844   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK|           | 20000 |    97K|  1844   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | LARGE_TAB | 20000 |    97K|  1842   (1)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*Get Data*

Knowing the upper bound ID you may query as simple as

```
select * from large_tab
where id > 0 and id <= 10000   ---<<< your upper bound here
```

Note that you do not need the `ORDER BY` at all to get the requested count, so this will be a very afficient *full table scan*.

Two final remarks

- to get 1M rows from a table  **do not** try to somehow deploy an **index** in your access. If you want to optimize you need *partitioning schema* based in `ID`.
- If you do not need all columns, do not use `SELECT *` because as you saw in the plan, you will need to sort this unneeded data.

Answer (score 0):

fetching 1000000 record  and that is with  * (All columns) obviously will take time,
Steps suggestion :-

1. Retrieve only the required columns.
2. Make partitions for the table it will be more faster for more details about partitions visit [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/partconc.htm#:~:text=Each%20row%20in%20a%20partitioned,use%20of%20the%20partition%20key](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/partconc.htm#:%7E:text=Each%20row%20in%20a%20partitioned,use%20of%20the%20partition%20key)
3. if you post your data to auto ascending grid in the front end execution time gets shorten in Backend